# odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans) compiling error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to follow this tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom and I attach to my driver controll node but when I compile it the following error occurred

> error: request for member ‘sendTransform’ in ‘odom_broadcaster’, which is of non-class >type ‘tf::TransformBroadcaster*’

this is the line it refers to

> odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);

if I try to comment that line compile goes "well", but maybe I don't receive the transform for the base link?

Could someone help me?

EDIT 1: I'm sorry but I found somewhere that, that line chage from "tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster" to "tf::TransformBroadcaster *odom_broadcaster" so changed it but without a great idea of what i'm doing. So I restore the original version and now the error is:

> undefined reference to `tf::TransformBroadcaster::TransformBroadcaster()'

> undefined reference to 'tf::TransformBroadcaster::sendTransform(geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_std::allocator<void > const&)'

I'm sorry but i thought I restored everything but I was wrong.

any new suggestion?

thanks a lot

EDIT 2:

Finnaly it works, maybe not in the right way but it works.
I add the tf_broadcaster.cpp source in my source folder and also the line in my CMakelist.txt and compile it.
I think it's not correct but for the moment is enough.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65661/odom_broadcaster.sendtransform(odom_trans)-compiling-error/) by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message explains the problem, although it takes a bit of experience to understand what it means.

The error message says that you have declared `odom_broadcaster` as a `tf::TransformBroadcaster` *pointer*.  If so, then you need to call the `sendTransform` method using pointer-syntax:

```
odom_broadcaster->sendTransform(odom_trans)
```

Note that the tutorial you referenced declares `odom_broadcaster` as an object, not a pointer, so won't have the issue you're seeing.  Check to make sure you've followed the tutorial correctly.

**Edit:**
The new error message you're reporting (`undefined reference...`) is a linker error.  Make sure that you have a reference to the `tf` package in your `manifest.xml/package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`.  The appropriate syntax depends on whether you're using `catkin_make` or `rosmake`.  Have you tried following the initial `tf` tutorials [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29)?  The `create_pkg` command in Step 1 should have created the appropriate dependencies in your `package.xml` file.  Check to make sure there's a `tf` dependency listed.  If using catkin, make sure you have added the line:

```
target_link_libraries(turtle_tf_broadcaster ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Also, it's not specified in the tutorial, but you probably also need an additional line in `CMakeLists.txt` to add the `tf` package as a `catkin` component, as explained [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Finding_Dependent_CMake_Packages):

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS tf)
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-06-23**:
I follow the tutorial as is, but my experience in c# is closed to 0, so try to understand what the code do and attach it where I think is the correct place, this is the best I can do for the moment, Could you be a little more precise where I need to modify? thanks a lot for your answer

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-06-24**:
Please update your post with the code you're trying to run.  You should probably change the line that currently reads "tf::TransformBroadcaster *odom_broadcaster" to read "tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster".

**Comment by [xmfbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/9031/xmfbit/) on 2013-11-20**:
Thank you a lot!I tried to follow 'tf' tutorials and found the same problem with the questioner.And I add the tf dependency to the 'CMakeLists.txt' and it works!